# How to Windows Firewall path variables?

Tags: windows, java, firewall

Every time after a Java update I have to reconfigure the Firewall rule which gets pretty annoying after time...

```
c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
```

Is it possible to replace "jre1.8.0_131" with a variable within the Windows Firewall?

How do SysAdmins explain to their non-techie clients to modify a firewall rule? :/

Answer (score 1):

Ah..developer stupidity at it's finest. I never understood the lack of logic that causes many devs to put their files inside a variable named folder when they know they update it a lot. It's just stupid.

That aside, no, you cannot add a variable like %%SomeFolderName%% like there is for %%PROGRAMFILES%%.

If you try to `SETX SomeFolderName "c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe"` and then use 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule' to add it, attempting that will result in the Firewall Error:

```
"An error occurred while adding the rule."

Error: The parameter is incorrect

Status: The application name could not be resolved
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seriously... is there any way to solve this problem? I can't just manually edit the firewall rules on every system every two months and I also can't just not update a vulnerable application like Java...

Comment: Make a .bat file for the rules, and when java updates all you have to do is change the numbers in the file and re-run it. This would be the most user-friendly solution at this point. And do drop an e-mail to java about this naming issue. Many more things can fail because of it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. After all this time I doubt I'm going to be the first one to contact Java about this issue. They probably know and don't care.

Comment: Better to have multiple people tell them.

Comment: If you don't mind I'd like to delete the question because there is no solution to it.

Comment: The answer is that you cannot accomplish that at this moment. Should be there if anyone else wants to see.